# What does an mfd_cell structure describe in a linux kernel driver. Is it describing sub devices or a hierarchy node for sub-devices

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to understand the mfd framework in linux kernel to write my drivers but there seems to be hardly any documentation and the mfd core itself doesnt seem to have much helpful comments. So, I am trying to understand what the mfd_cell structure describes. That seems to be the basis here. What I m particularly interested in finding out is if this used as a general abstraction for 'x' number of sub-devices or is it intended/useful for a full hierarchy of sub-devices.

Comment: got any information on mfd device driver programming. Please let me know if your still working on that.

Comment: yes. I am still working on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An MFD is a device that contains several sub-devices. For instance, in embedded systems a PMIC usually contains a battery manager, a charger and sometimes devices with unrelated functions like a USB PHY, an Audio codec, a Real-Time Clock, ...

A cell is meant to describe a sub-device. The mfd subsystem will use the information registered in that structure to create a platform device for each sub-device, along with the platform_data for the sub-device.
You can specify more advanced things like the resources used by this device and suspend-resume operations (to be called from the driver for the sub-device).

The new platform devices that are created will have the cell structure as their platform data and can access the *real* platform data through `cell->platform_data`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal driver example for a total simple driver? I am currently struggling with parenting two sub-device drivers with MFD. All of the existing drivers seem to be so totally complex for a simple use case like mine!

Comment: The mfd cells describe sub devices and you will have to match the naming of your drivers with the sub-devices for that to have a proper binding.